# General practice to specify a break after a default clause?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [break in a case with return.. and for default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957038/break-in-a-case-with-return-and-for-default)

If I have a switch statement:

```
switch()
{
    case 1: ...
    case 2: ...
    ...
    default:
        break;
}
```

Is there any reason for the break in the default clause? I see this in quite a few places, but isn't it unnecessary? What is the general practice?

Can another case label come *after* the default clause?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957038/break-in-a-case-with-return-and-for-default).

Comment: I think you figured it out. It's not C++ specific. If you or someone else writes another another case afterwards, it's safer to have the break clause. There may be another reason.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. In C++, the example given by the OP would not compile without the `break` statement. C++ makes `break` mandatory if the last case of a `switch` is empty. This question was marked as a duplicate of a C question. C is a different language, and has slightly different requirements for the `switch` statement.

Comment: @NikosC. It's not the *`break`* that's mandatory in C++, it's a *primary expression* that's mandatory, this could also be the empty statement `;` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/bBwmJx)), and there is no difference to C (see [demo](https://ideone.com/b1II61)).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Can another case label come after the default clause?*

Yes, you are allowed to place the default clause anywhere within the switch block.