# Is possible to use if else statement within a switch statement?

Tags: c

I am trying to insert an if else statement in the switch statement however only the else statement prints out. Any help please? I'm referring to the third switch statement.

```
        num_remain= num_temp/10;

    switch (num_remain)
    {

    case 0: printf(" "); break;
    case 2: if (num=0)
                        printf("Twenty");
                        else printf(" And Twenty"); break; // If num= 0 or not, it just prints "And Twenty".
    case 3: printf(" Thirty"); break;
    case 4: printf(" Fourty"); break;
    case 5: printf(" Fifty"); break;
    case 6: printf(" Sixty"); break;
    case 7: printf(" Seventy"); break;
    case 8: printf(" Eighty"); break;
    case 9: printf(" Ninety"); break;

    }
```

Comment: num == 0, not num = 0.

Comment: Nothing to do with switch; you simply have a typo (`==` instead of `=`).

Comment: At least 10 times a day such question is posted...

Comment: I just tried it and it is still not working.

Comment: @TemiIsaac - then there's something else wrong with your code that you're not showing us. How is `num` defined and where is it set?

Comment: num is defined at the beginning of the main function. I'm not being allowed to post the complete code.

Comment: void main()
{
 int num=0; int num_initial=0; int num_remain=0; int num_final=0; int num_temp=0;

Comment: So `num` is initially set to 0. It is never modified and you somehow expect it to have a value other than 0?

Comment: It will be modified. The user is asked to input a value for num. printf("Enter a number up to three digits: ");
 scanf("%d", &num);

Comment: Fixed it guys!!! The problem was with my variable

Answer (score 5):

```
if (num=0)
```

You missed an `=` sign which causes this to be an assignment `if(num=0)` is the same as `if(0)` and thus will always be false. It should be

```
if (num==0)
```

or better yet:

```
if(0 == num)
```

which will prevent a mistake like this by throwing an error.

---

**edit:**
You say that doesn't fix the problem, then there's something else wrong. Here's an example code where it does work:

```
int i = 2;
int j = 0;

switch(i)
{
    case 0:
       printf("it's 0\n");
       break;
    case 1:
       printf("it's 1\n");
       break;
    case 2:
       printf("it's 2\n");
       if(0 == j)
           printf("j is 0\n");
       else
           printf("hit the else\n");
       break;
    default:
       printf("The default\n");
}
```

This code is a proof of concept for what you're trying to do. It prints "it's 2" followed by "j is 0" because that works. If your code isn't working still you're doing something else you're not showing us, or your variables are not set how you think. Check your variables, print them before entering the switch.

Comment: I'll check my variables. Thanks

Comment: @TemiIsaac - no problem. If you find something else let us know and we can help.

Comment: @Mike : I have a question, maybe you can answer. Is this a good/bad/not important thing to put a "break;" after the default ?

Comment: @Joze - that is [a common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957038/break-in-a-case-with-return-and-for-default) short answer is it doesn't matter, it's just going to drop out either way... some say it looks better, I don't usually do it however.

Comment: if default is used at anywhere beside the last statement then you should put a break.

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was with my variable. Thannks.

Comment: @TemiIsaac - Glad you got it ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (num==0)
```

and not

```
if (num=0)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it is still not working.

Comment: Fixed it!!! The problem was with my variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The others have answered your question, but to make it easier for you, you can also introduce scope which makes it easier to read and write for programmers:

```
// the braces introduce scope, and make it easier to read and find your bugs.
case 2:
{ 
  if (0 == num)
  {
    printf("Twenty");
  }
  else 
  {
    printf(" And Twenty");
  }
} break;
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. I appreciate the help. I'll look through my code again to see if an error exists somewhere else.

Comment: Fixed it!!! The problem was with my variable. Thanks

Comment: If something helped you, you should vote it up.

Comment: I can't. It says reputation of '15' required